# How to get each div inside a main div in Angular 6?

Tags: typescript, angular6

I have a div element containing other three div's inside it. Now I need to get all the divs inside a div using Angular 6. I am using `@ViewChildren` for doing this. But I am able to fetch only first element inside the main div.

How do I get all the div elements inside 'mainDiv'? Here's my code:

```
<div class="mainDiv" #divElements>
  <div>First Element</div>
  <div>Second Element</div>
  <div>Third Element</div>
</div>
```

And here's my typescript code:

```
export class sampleComponent{
  @ViewChildren('divElements') mainDiv; 
  constructor() {}
  }
  ngOnInit(){
    console.log(mainDiv);
  }
}
```

Please guide me how to proceed with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#divElements is a localvaiable in template to fetch that particular HtmlElement in component we are using the
@ViewChild('divElements') annotation.

1. use localVariable for all remaining div tag to get their respective HtmlElement into your component (or)
2. Get it from **childNodes using the nativeElement from ElementRef** , check the below class for better understanding

```
 export class AppComponent  {
    
      name = 'Angular 6';
    
      @ViewChild('divElements')
      public divElements: ElementRef;
    
      ngOnInit() {
        console.log(this.divElements.nativeElement.childNodes);
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the usual js methods to do this. For example - document.getElementsByClassName("mainDiv")